# Some anchors within the cooking and programmers faq sidebar don't work

Tags: bug, meta-faq, broken-link

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Custom sections in FAQ don't work right](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104861/custom-sections-in-faq-dont-work-right)

At [Cooking](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/faq):

- What about other food-related questions?

At [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq):

- Can I ask career advice questions?
- What about other programming related questions?

For both sites, the anchors used don't seem to exist, the page always scrolls up to the first question.

<sub><sup>(Not sure - should this have been two separate posts, one for each site?)</sup></sub>

**EDIT**

Comments suggest it might be a browser-dependant issue, I'm seeing this using Firefox 6.0.2 on Windows XP SP3.

Comment: Repro'd for all links to anchors that end with `-questions` (Safari 5.0.3, Mac OS X).

Comment: I believe this is the same problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104861/custom-sections-in-faq-dont-work-right and the reason you see it scroll to the first is because the custom sections come directly after the first "official" one in each case.

Comment: @staticbeast You're probably right there. I guess I didn't find that question because I didn't know about the faq being put together from different types of sections, or how to tell them apart. Voted to close as duplicate ...

Comment: To answer your meta-question, no, you did the right thing. If one site has a problem, report it on its individual meta. Once you see the same problem on multiple sites, it's a network problem, and deserves a single question here on MSO.

Comment: @Popular Demand Thanks for making that clear. I had posted this on the meta.cooking and on meta.programmers a week ago or so, but both got deleted within a few hours. I just remembered today and thought I needed to get back to it ...

Comment: Deleted, really? Huh. Perhaps the deleters already knew it was a network issue?

Comment: @Popular Demand Well, in that case, I'd have expected them to migrate it to here. I just assumed it was due to the more technical nature of it, as opposed to the more common "how do we want our site to function locically"-type of questions.

Comment: Well, _if_ they did already know, it was probably from an existing MSO post (such as the one that this is a duplicate of); in that case, migration would be the wrong call, because it would just be creating a duplicate here. But they should've let you know, in my opinion anyways.

Comment: @takrl I just looked on Programmers Meta and I see your post. I'm sorry I missed it when it was originally posted. I would've pointed you to the duplicate here instead. I have no clue why it was just outright deleted. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Anna Lear No problem, I've been around here long enough now to not get "enraged" by that, so to speak. Nevertheless, I'd have appreciated a comment regarding the "why" ...

Comment: @takrl Yeah, I hear ya. You and me both.